Solving a system of equations involving Gaussian Integrals numerically
I wish to solve the following system of equations numerically in any software, I tried in Mathematica using the expectation functions, but I have a difficulty in understanding how to go about solving them, as these have to be solved simultaneously. The equation are as follows,
\begin{gather}
    m_c = \langle\langle \iint Dx_1Dx_2 \mathfrak{b} \cos \Theta(x_1, x_2, \mathfrak{b}) \rangle\rangle_\mathfrak{b}\newline
    m_s = \langle\langle \iint Dx_1Dx_2 \mathfrak{b} \sin \Theta(x_1, x_2, \mathfrak{b}) \rangle\rangle_\mathfrak{b}\newline
    q_c = \langle\langle \iint Dx_1Dx_2 \mathfrak{b} \cos^2 \Theta(x_1, x_2, \mathfrak{b}) \rangle\rangle_\mathfrak{b}\newline
    q_s = \langle\langle \iint Dx_1Dx_2 \mathfrak{b} \sin^2 \Theta(x_1, x_2, \mathfrak{b}) \rangle\rangle_\mathfrak{b}\newline
    q_{sc} = \langle\langle \iint Dx_1Dx_2 \mathfrak{b} \cos \Theta(x_1, x_2, \mathfrak{b}) \sin(\Theta(x_1, x_2, \mathfrak{b}) \rangle\rangle_\mathfrak{b}\newline
    C_1 = \frac{1-\Lambda}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\langle\langle \iint Dx_1Dx_2 \mathfrak{b} (\bar{Q_1}x_1 + \bar{Q_3}x_2)\cos\Theta(x_1, x_2, \mathfrak{b})\rangle\rangle_\mathfrak{b}\newline
    C_2 = \frac{1-\Lambda}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\langle\langle \iint Dx_1Dx_2 \mathfrak{b} (\bar{Q_3}x_1 + \bar{Q_3}x_2)\cos\Theta(x_1, x_2, \mathfrak{b})\rangle\rangle_\mathfrak{b}\newline
    S_1 = \frac{1-\Lambda}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\langle\langle \iint Dx_1Dx_2 \mathfrak{b} (\bar{Q_1}x_1 + \bar{Q_3}x_2)\sin\Theta(x_1, x_2, \mathfrak{b})\rangle\rangle_\mathfrak{b} \newline
    S_2 = \frac{1-\Lambda}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\langle\langle \iint Dx_1Dx_2 \mathfrak{b} (\bar{Q_3}x_1 + \bar{Q_3}x_2)\sin\Theta(x_1, x_2, \mathfrak{b})\rangle\rangle_\mathfrak{b}
\end{gather}
\begin{gather}
        \iint Dx_1Dx_2 := \iint \frac{dx_1dx_2}{2\pi/\sqrt{\mathrm{det}}}\exp\left(-1/2\begin{bmatrix}
            x_1 & x_2
        \end{bmatrix}Q\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2
        \end{bmatrix}\right)\newline
        Q = \begin{bmatrix}
            Q_1 & Q_2 \newline
            Q_3 & Q_4
        \end{bmatrix}\newline
        Q_1 = \frac{\alpha~ \mathrm{det}Q}{(1-\Lambda)^2}[S_1^2q_c + 2S_1(1-C_1)q_{sc} + (1-C_1)^2q_s]\newline
        Q_2 = \frac{\alpha~ \mathrm{det}Q}{(1-\Lambda)^2}[(1-S_2)^2q_c + 2C_2(1-S_2)q_{sc} + C_2^2q_s]\newline
        \begin{split}
        Q_3 = -\frac{\alpha~ \mathrm{det}Q}{(1-\Lambda)^2}[S_1(1-S_2)q_c + (1-C_1)C_2q_s) + (1 - S_2 - C_1 + S_2C_1 + S_1C_2)q_{sc}]
        \end{split}
    \end{gather}
and $\Theta$ can be written as a function of the $x_1, x_2$, and is given by,
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        -[(1-\Lambda)m_c + x_1] \sin\Theta + [(1-\Lambda)m_s + x_2]\cos\Theta \\ = \alpha[C_2 \sin^2\Theta - S_1\cos^2\Theta + (C_1 - S_2)\sin\Theta\cos\Theta]
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Ideally I should have written a minimal example but I really have don't know how to reduce this system.
But essentially, every equation relies on all other, and the function to be integrated over itself is a function of every other term. Requesting any help in solving such systems, thank you.
